# Wordpress - Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN'

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, undefined, constants

I am building my first Wordpress site, I just downloaded and installed v3.9.1. I bought a theme (rustik3) and I am trying to install it, but I am running into these errors produced by WP_DEBUG:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 501

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 502

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 503

Notice: Undefined variable: item_info in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 23
```

I have done some googling, and I'm starting to think that the last Wordpress update made it so that the Redux Framework is deprecated and cannot be used. This is just a hunch though. As of right now, the theme installs, but it shows up as completely blank - either when I go to `http://localhost` or when I am trying to customize it in the Wordpress UI. I haven't looked into the last part of the error messages log (line 23 error)...but it is just an undefined variable so I might be able to tackle that one myself. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is what the chunk of code looks like in `options.php`:

```
array(
            'id' => 'google_webfonts',
            'type' => 'google_webfonts',
            'title' => __('Enable Google Webfonts', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN), 
            'sub_desc' => __('Pick from over 600 Google Webfonts to use on the site. Then select below which elements you want to apply it to.', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN),
                'desc' => __('', Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN)
      ),
```

**UPDATE**

I did a text search through all of the wordpress files for `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN` and the only spot it appears is in the above chunk of code...

**UPDATE**

This code is what loads the text domain in the theme I have...I am not familiar with what a text domain is - but this might be relevant:

```
public function load_textdomain() {
        if ( isset( $this->textdomain_loaded ) )
            return $this->textdomain_loaded;

        $textdomain = $this->get('TextDomain');
        if ( ! $textdomain ) {
            $this->textdomain_loaded = false;
            return false;
        }

        if ( is_textdomain_loaded( $textdomain ) ) {
            $this->textdomain_loaded = true;
            return true;
        }

        $path = $this->get_stylesheet_directory();
        if ( $domainpath = $this->get('DomainPath') )
            $path .= $domainpath;
        else
            $path .= '/languages';

        $this->textdomain_loaded = load_theme_textdomain( $textdomain, $path );
        return $this->textdomain_loaded;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the above code?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the below answer - I can now see the theme (it isn't showing up as a blank page) - but I am still getting the same errors...and a few more:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 501

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 502

Notice: Use of undefined constant Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN - assumed 'Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 503

Notice: Undefined index: rustik_body_img in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 263

Notice: Undefined index: rustik_custom_favicon in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 210

Notice: Undefined index: rustik_custom_css in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 239

Notice: Undefined index: rustik_google_analytics in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 224
```

This is the only other place `$item_info` is set:

```
    $item_info = '<div class="rustik-opts-section-desc"><div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"><img width="300px" alt="Current theme preview" src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/themes/rustik3/screenshot.png"></div><div style="float: left;">';
    $item_info .= '<p class="rustik-opts-item-data description item-uri">' . __('<strong>Theme URL:</strong> ', Rustik_TEXT_DOMAIN) . '<a href="' . $item_uri . '" target="_blank">' . $item_uri . '</a></p>';
    $item_info .= '<p class="rustik-opts-item-data description item-author">' . __('<strong>Author:</strong> ', Rustik_TEXT_DOMAIN) . ($author_uri ? '<a href="' . $author_uri . '" target="_blank">' . $author . '</a>' : $author) . '</p>';
    $item_info .= '<p class="rustik-opts-item-data description item-version">' . __('<strong>Version:</strong> ', Rustik_TEXT_DOMAIN) . $version . '</p>';
    $item_info .= '<p class="rustik-opts-item-data description item-description">' . $description . '</p>';
    $item_info .= '<p class="rustik-opts-item-data description item-tags">' . __('<strong>Tags:</strong> ', Rustik_TEXT_DOMAIN) . implode(', ', $tags) . '</p>';
    $item_info .= '</div></div>';
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56666/discussion-between-ewizard-and-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to:  http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/rustik-minimalist-e-commerce-ready-theme/

The theme will work on wordpress 3.9, but it also requires the WooCommerce 2.1 plugin. Do you have that installed? http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

It's possible the defined constant is in the dependencies.

Comment: I can see the theme now!!! so thanks for that! but I am still getting the same errors...I'm updating my question now...to add the errors that I am seeing - no 50 pts yet :) (still need to fix this stuff).

Comment: Okay, well I would recommend that you also redownload the theme and make sure everything gets properly moved to the theme folder. Just to be sure. Something has to be missing because you should be able to find a define statment for the undefined constant.

Comment: i think i fixed it - i asked a question on the wordpress specific site here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152506/notice-use-of-undefined-constant-redux-text-domain-assumed-redux-text-domain...see that question...only one error left...and i posted relevant code - i'll give you the points for helping with what you said (making my theme visible) - but take a look at the link first...and read my updates in the question.

Comment: ha funny, I had just found your other post... Try adding global infront of item_info. If you remove the dot it would work but naturally you would loose earlier strings added to the variable.

Comment: just the word `global`?

Comment: It's a long shot but yes. If the varable was already defined earlier as a global variable then to include it in another file it also needs to be declared as a global. So just ad global infront of the variable. If you don't want to 'add' to the variable then just remove the string concatinator operator... .= is to 'add' more text to the string. Just = is to add a string to an empty variable

Comment: i looked at php docs and tried this `GLOBAL $item_info` but i get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.=' (T_CONCAT_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/theme-functions.php on line 13`...I am not familiar with the ins and outs of the theme yet...but it may need the string concatinator operator...im not sure.

Comment: i think it is probably required...because it is a store theme...and $item_info probably needs to be added to as items are added or something along those lines (judging from the html that is being stored in it)

Comment: crazy idea...but what if i changed the outer `'` to `"` and then made all the inner quotes `'`? I am thinking that `'` might not be working because it is supposed to be a string...is this right?

Comment: Search the project for more locations of $item_info. If there are none then get ride of the .= and make it a = but if there are more then it has to remain as is.

Comment: it is used in one other place (options.php)...gonna update my question again...let me know if you see anyway around having to use the `.=`

Comment: try makeing them both global variables (lowercase so global). The idea of global is that they will have a larger scope then just the function or file they are in because right now php is treating them as seperate variables but my guess is they are actually the same variable. In both cases the variable is a String right?

Comment: hmm `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/wp-content/themes/rustik3/admin/options.php on line 1112` why doesnt it like the `=` there?

Comment: nevermind the error - i needed to declare the variable first as `global` in options.php before I could use it...but I'm getting the same error using global (the undefined variable error)...any ideas?

Comment: Line 1111 ends with a semicolon right? What happens when you make it $item_info = ''; And remove the other lines? I would simply the problem to the minimum to get it to work then add back in the other parts.

Comment: @shoeffman - the error goes away if i use `=` instead of `.=` if that is what you are asking (essentially)?

Comment: line 1111 is just a blank line...line 1110 is the end of an if/else conditional

Comment: there is a lot going on when `$item_info` is stored...lots of functions involved...i see what you are saying...build from the ground up...which i can try...see if any of those functions are being referenced incorrectly...which would in turn not store anything in the variable...right?

Comment: $item_list .= 'sadf'; is the same as writing $item_list = $item_list . 'asdf'; So, if both variables (in options.php and the theme-functions.php) are global and it is still complaining about an undefined variable what is happening is the concatination has nothing to concatinate too. If it still just doesn't work with a regular equals sign then that means something else in the line is breaking.

Comment: i think i might do what you said and just try to build that section of the code from the ground up...see if i can pinpoint the error - i think something in that first part `$item_info = xxx` must be wrong...and then the concatenation isn't working from there maybe

Comment: Okay, you might also want to look into tools like Xdebug. It lets you step through lines of code as its executing and it might help you out for this and future problems. http://xdebug.org/

Comment: @shoeffman - one more question lol...does this look syntactically correct to you? its from the line where `$item_info` is first set...im not sure exactly whats going on here: `src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/themes/rustik3/screenshot.png"`

Comment: why does it look like this? `'.get_option('home').'` with the period inside the end of that segment...should this be outside the single quote?

Comment: because it's 'this is a string' . function() . 'this is a string'; When you want to add strings togeather you need the dots. Your code snippet above looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function load_textdomain() {
    if ( isset( $this->textdomain_loaded ) )
        return $this->textdomain_loaded;

    $textdomain = $this->get('TextDomain');
    if ( ! $textdomain ) {
        $this->textdomain_loaded = false;
        return false;
    }

    if ( is_textdomain_loaded( $textdomain ) ) {
        $this->textdomain_loaded = true;
        return true;
    }

    $path = $this->get_stylesheet_directory();
    if ( $domainpath = $this->get('DomainPath') )
        $path .= $domainpath;
    else
        $path .= '/languages';

    define('redux_TEXT_DOMAIN', $textdomain);
    $this->textdomain_loaded = load_theme_textdomain( $textdomain, $path );
    return $this->textdomain_loaded;
}
```

Comment: I already resolved the errors with `Redux_TEXT_DOMAIN`...but do you see any advantages to doing it the way you have it above?

Comment: as discussed: you can remove the . before the = , within the function its local namespacing so the $user_info in your options has no effect on it. Also its only a admin notice so sign up for some emails so even if there was something else, its ok!

Comment: cool - so you are saying that I dont have to worry about the last error really because it has to do with admin (not the site the user will use)...and you think that the `.=` isn't working because the variable is being used inside a function which restricts its scope so that when `$item_info` is set in `options.php` - there is no way for it to be seen in `theme-functions.php` when it is inside that function? thanks!